# how to update background color of a view in android?

Tags: android

Actually i am trying to set the background color of a view class but i am not getting what i wanted. What to do now?

I have tried to set background color of a view like mentioned below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#FF0">
 <view
    android:layout_width="144dp"
    android:layout_height="144dp"
    android:background="#F0F">

</view>


</LinearLayout>
```

here the view background color must have been changed to purple but it is still the grey.

Comment: Try using full color code like #FF0000 (red color)

Comment: Give orientation to parent layout (horizontal or vertical) and use full-color code

Answer (score 0):

The `view` tag is for using another `View` inside with the attribute name. That is why is not working.

You want to use `View` the uppercase make the difference. A `View` is the base class of every other `View`.

Usually harcoded colors are a bad practice, look for the colors.xml file and there add a color, then you can use like this:

```
android:background="@colors/yourColor">
```

You already have a couple of colors there like `primary`.
You can also use android default colors `@android:colors/...`

Answer (score 0):

The best method in implementing colors to your app is to write a color in here ** drawable -> values -> colors ** and after that make sure you called it correctly in your XML activity like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/yourcolorname">

<view
    android:layout_width="144dp"
    android:layout_height="144dp"
    android:background="@color/yourcolorname">
</view>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

V is upper-case in `View`.

```
 <View
    android:layout_width="144dp"
    android:layout_height="144dp"
    android:background="#F0F">

</View>
```

Answer (score 0):

Provide orientation to your parent layout and make `<view>...</view>` to Upper case `<View>...</View>`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#FF0">
       <View
          android:layout_width="144dp"
          android:layout_height="144dp"
          android:background="#F0F"/>

</LinearLayout>
```